# TFS build to create workspace in NetworkSharedPath

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, release, devops

Currently my TFS  build is creating the workspace in build machine and all my remaining task  are performed in a network share in UNIX machine. So i copy my workspace to that network share before proceeding with the build. Is there any way to directly create the workspace in NetworkShare, so that i can stop copying process.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Are you aware that if you're using the new build system on TFS 2015 or later you could easily set up a non-Windows build environment?

Comment: yes i am using  TFS 2015. But the only problem is 70 % of my task are dependent on WIndows machine . Tasks like C# builds MSI creation etc and remaining 30 % is in UNIX by a different build. From TFS i just trigger this UNIX build. So i should use Windows machine as my build machine and i just want get workspace to NetworkShare

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the UNIX project have dependencies which generated on windows build, I am afraid you have to add a copy task to copy them first, unless you can build the windows and UNIX projects on the same agent, but generally it's not possible.

However if you want to build them on a network shared path, then you just need to [deploy a new build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) and set the network path as the working folder. Thus you can directly reference the dependencies on the shared path.

[image]

Comment: @TVSuser1654136 Have you resolved the issue? any update?